# Excluding All and including only one class in a package

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I use maven jar plugin and I would like to include only one or two classes in a package. There are include and exclude options [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) in Apache maven docs.
But this doesn't let me include only A.java since there is an exclude for parent path.

If I only apply include this time only that class is being exported and it won't be practical defining all the classes in the project apart from the excluded ones!

If there are 100 classes under `products` is there a way to include only A.java practically.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>

            <excludes>                        
                <exclude>
                    **/customer/products/*
                </exclude>
            </excludes>

            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>     
                <include>com/customer/products/A.java</include>         
            </includes>

      ....
    </plugin>
```

Comment: It sounds you should make separate modules and only put the classes under `src/main/java` you really want to package...having the need for excludes/includes within a module for maven-jar-plugin is usually a build smell....

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your comment. I thought something similar. Excluding 
 that package completely and include only X classes in different mvn task and putting that class into ClassPath should work. Just wanted to learn if there is any other trick.,